# overleaf: 3 error compiling. I think is the same prob

Tags: compilation-error

on my .tex I receive 3 error (that do not compromise the compilation) that one:

> > Unused global option(s):

```
  ‪./main.tex‬ Package fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (85.35826pt): Make it at least 111.64067pt, for example: \setlength{\headheight}{111.64067pt}. You might also make \topmargin smaller to compensate:(fancyhdr) \addtolength{\topmargin}{-26.28241pt}.

  ‪./main.tex‬ Package fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (85.35826pt): Make it at least 110.6211pt, for example: \setlength{\headheight}{110.6211pt}. You might also make \topmargin smaller to compensate:(fancyhdr) \addtolength{\topmargin}{-25.26283pt}.
```

this is a minimal example, but it give me more error (because it lack the images and so on)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a3paper]{article}
   \usepackage[italian]{babel}  %--setta regole lingua italiana
          % \usepackage{fbb}  %--- per l'uso del font Bembo       
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage[document]{ragged2e} %--per allineamento testo a dx, sx o giustificato
   \usepackage{multicol} %------ per formattare pagine a più colonne
   \usepackage{tcolorbox} %--- per le caselle di testo I pagina
   \usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}%----- uso font garamond matematico
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%----- uso font garamond
   \usepackage[a3paper, top=50mm,bottom=15mm,left=15mm, 
   right=15mm, headheight=40mm, headsep=2\baselineskip]{geometry}
   \usepackage{fancyhdr} %--pacchetto per layout pagina
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %--rimuove la linea sotto l'intestazione
   \usepackage{hyperref} %--- per i link
\newcommand\filetto{\newline\strut\raisebox{0.7ex}{\makebox[\linewidth]{\hrulefill}}\newline} %-definisce il filetto con gli spazi da inserire a fine articolo
%--------costruisce l'intestazione generale ufficiale----------
\newcounter{thenumero} 
\setcounter{thenumero}{0} % numero del particolare esemplare

\fancyhead[C]{%

\makebox[0pt][c]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=39mm]{banner_corto_completo.png}}%
\llap{\raisebox{15mm}{\includegraphics[width=70mm,height=39mm,keepaspectratio]{futura.jpg}\hspace*{60mm}}}%
\rlap{\raisebox{15mm}{\hspace*{60mm}\includegraphics[width=70mm,height=39mm,keepaspectratio]{estralia_bkg_trasparente.png}}}%

}

  \vspace*{-4ex}
 
\pagestyle{fancy}%%%%%%%%%%% <-------------------
%---------------costruisce l'intestazione speciale---------

%---imp. colori e forma dei box di I pagina----------
\tcbset{colback=black!5!!,
        colframe=blue!5!black!60!,
        size=small,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,width=0.333\textwidth,box align=top,height=7cm,nobeforeafter}
   \setlength{\headheight}{3cm}
   
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INIZIO DOCUMENTO %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}%--------begin document ---------------------

%-----------PAG 1--------------------------------------
%------------------------ I linea di box --------------
\noindent%------linea I box I -------------

   \begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=\hyperlink{1_1}{bla bla blaI},halign=justify]
       pippo    \\
      \vspace{2ex}
      \noindent
    bla bla bla bla   bla bla bla bla    bla bla bla bla   bla bla bla bla    bla bla bla bla   bla bla bla bla  bla bla bla bla   bla bla bla bla    bla bla bla bla   bla bla bla bla    bla bla bla bla   bla bla bla bla  bla bla bla bla   bla bla bla bla    bla bla bla bla   bla bla bla bla    bla bla bla bla   bla bla bla bla 
   \end{tcolorbox} 
   \end{document}
```

So, please, tells me what I need to do to eliminate that error. They are not definitive for the compilation (it do that) but I would obtain a perfect source.

Thank you

Renato

Comment: they are warnings not an error and you have quoted the exact fix required, which is in the message. add `\setlength{\headheight}{110.6211pt}` to your preamble

Comment: use a code block not a quote when showing error messages as otherwise line endings are lost which in most cases makes them completely not understandable

Comment: Please have a look at https://www.guitex.org/home/images/doc/GuideGuIT/guidaemc.pdf If you don't provide a short test document which reproduces the warnings, how to you expect people to tell you which of your class options causes the `unused global option` warning? We can't know which options you use!

Comment: But if you are using `geometry` or a similar package, you should use it to adjust `\headheight`. Note that it would definitely be possible to produce a minimal example demonstrating this problem.

Comment: Can you please add line breaks to your code? Currently it is not clear which parts are commented out and which are not. (you can avoid errors about missing images if you use `example-image`, this should be included in all major latex distributions)

Comment: If you look at the complete warning message it tells you which option isn't used: `LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [a3paper].`

Comment: so, what I've to correct?

Comment: Please don't format code as quotes. I've changed it to code formatting, but it is still almost unreadable. Can you please paste it here with proper line breaks so we can actually see enough to help you? As @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz says, we have no way of knowing what you're actually using and what's commented out.

Comment: If you're loading `geometry` and don't actually have that commented, then you can ignore the unused global option warning @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz mentioned. If `geometry` is commented, uncomment it. And feed `geometry` your head height. If you want more specific help, you'll need to provide code people can use.

Comment: @RenatoP You can probably remove the option, but hard to say if we don't know what are comments and what not in your code. As said before: Please do add line breaks!

Comment: @RenatoP Thanks for the line breaks! As you use the geometry package with the `a3paper` option, you don't need it as class option. Use `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` instead.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz:thank you, i've replaced the first line, and I have "just" 2 error:
Package fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (85.35826pt): Make it at least 111.64067pt, for example: \setlength{\headheight}{111.64067pt}. You might also make \topmargin smaller to compensate:(fancyhdr) \addtolength{\topmargin}{-26.28241pt}.

 
‪./main.tex‬
Package fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (85.35826pt): Make it at least 110.6211pt, for example: \setlength{\headheight}{110.6211pt}. You might also make \topmargin smaller to compensate:(fancyhdr) \addtole

Comment: I thgink it matter the fancyhdr command. Isn't it?

Comment: @RenatoP As said by David and cfr in earlier comments, your headheight is too small. Replace `headheight=40mm` with a tall enough value. The warning even tells you which value you need.

Comment: almost solved!: I've changed headheight=40mm to    \setlength{\headheight}{5cm} as compiler said and it remain just 1 error: Unused global option(s): that I cannot understand what is it
Thank you to everyone!